# Is the set of permuted digits countable

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory

I wish to know whether it the following set is countable:

The set of all numbers with decimal expansions which simply permute the digits $\{0,1,2,...,9\}$

To put it more formally: a digit $x = 0.x_1x_2... \in [0,1]$ is apart of our set when $\{x_1, x_2,..., x_{10}\} = \{0,1,2,...,9\} = \{x_{11}, x_{12}, ..., x_{20}\} = ... $

e.g.
X = 0.01234567899876543210.... going on indefinitely

Here's what I've thought of:

We can enumerate all the possibility of sequences using 9! digits, i.e. you can define a function $f(x)$ such that

$$f(0.0123456789) = 1$$

$$f(0.0123456798) = 2$$

$$...$$

$$f(0.9876543210) = 9!$$

So for any number with such a property we can simply write $\phi(x) = f(0.x_1x_2...x_{10})f(0.x_{11}x_{12}...x_{20})...$. To make this function injective, lets say it sends our digits to the natural numbers base 9!. I believe this would make $\phi$ injective and since you can convert a number from any base to another, it would make it injective to $\mathbb{N}$ proper. Thus it is countable.

Comment: Your number $\phi(x)$ could potentially have infinitely many digits, which doesn't make sense for a map to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: you need a more clear and precise definition of the real numbers in this set. you offer a vague desciption along with a vague example.

Comment: This set is uncountable.
You can define an injection from $\{0, 1\}^{\mathbf{N}}$ according to 
$
f(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dotsc)
= 0.[x_1(1-x_1)23456789][x_2(1-x_2)23456789]\dotsc
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is uncountable. As I note in my comment, your approach is flawed.

As you correctly state, we can enumerate the permutations of the 10 possible digits to get a bijection $f$ between all numbers of the form $0.x_1x_2\cdots x_{10}$ (with $\{x_1,\dots,x_{10}\} = \{0,\dots,9\}$) and the set $\{1,2,\dots,10!\}$. With that, we can define a bijection between your set and the set of all functions from $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$ to $\{1,2,\dots,10!\}$. In particular, for any $x$ from your set and $n \in \Bbb N$, define
$$
[\phi(x)](n) = f(0.x_{10n + 1},x_{10n+2},\dots,x_{10n+10}).
$$
That is, your set $S_1$ is equivalent to the set
$$
S_2 = \{1,2,\dots,10!\}^{\Bbb N} = \{g\mid g:\Bbb N \to \{1,2,\dots,10!\}\}.
$$
It is easy to define an injective map $\psi$ from $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ to $S_2$. In particular, for any subset $X \subset \Bbb N$, define
$$
[\psi(X)](n) = 
\begin{cases}1 & n \in X\\ 2 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, we have $|S_1| = |S_2| \geq |\mathcal P(\Bbb N)| > |\Bbb N|$. So, $S_1$ is uncountable.

Comment: +1, but I think you and the OP both mean to say $10!$ instead of $9!$.

Comment: @Ravi True, edited